# What does "Сейчас всё брошу и побегу!" mean?

Tags: выражения

Here's a dialog from [a Japanese tutorial:](https://s00.yaplakal.com/pics/pics_original/1/2/4/14800421.jpg)

> **A:** Слушай, зай, принеси нам кофе, а?
>
> **B:** Сейчас всё брошу и побегу! Видишь, у меня фильм начинается.

“Сейчас всё брошу и побегу!” is literally translated as "I will throw everything and run!" but I suppose that really it means something else and I have no idea what exactly.

Comment: Can sb explain why it is "off-topic"?

Comment: - because, just like it said in the exact description: "Questions asking for translations are off-topic unless prior research effort is clearly indicated; we're here to help you learn, not provide a bulk translation service." Also, please, avoid posting redundant text decorations like  :::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::.  Also, tend to use text quotes rather screen shots.

Comment: @shabunc Sorry, don't have Japanese keyboard.

Comment: @shabunc OK “Сейчас всё брошу и побегу!” is translated as "I will throw everything and run!" but I suppose that really it means smth else

Comment: @shabunc What problems do you have now?

Comment: I've edited question further to gave you idea what is this about. Thank you for collaborating, now question is re-opened.

Comment: @shabunc Thanks.

Comment: @Expelhares  why do you need Japanese keyboard for Russian text?

Comment: Pay attention to meanings #3 and #4 here: https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/бросить#Verb

Comment: @YellowSky So you think that it means "I will leave all off and run!", do you?

Comment: That's a way to refuse doing what you were asked, "Now I'll stop doing everything [I'm doing] and run [to do what you asked]."

Comment: +1 because the meaning is not evident from the words used

Comment: For additional context, the Japanese translation is: "You're kidding, right? The movie is about to start," which, regardless of the Russian sentence, might have a nuance of "You should [drop (the idea of buying coffee)](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/drop-a-case) and hurry up!"

Comment: the sarcasm. He won't do it, of course. :>

Answer (score 4):

Here "все брошу" would be better translated "I'll drop everything". While "бросать" does mean "to throw" it doesn't necessarily mean to throw like one would a ball. It often is used in senses closer to "throw away", "drop", "get rid of", or "leave". Here it is used metaphorically to mean to suddenly abandon an uncompleted activity as if one dropped the materials on the ground and left.

I suspect the utterance is this dialog is sarcastic. I would translate as:

> Sure, I'll just drop everything and run off and get that. `Cause you know my movie is about to start.

The motion verb "побежать" means to set off running. It is often used to mean that the person is leaving suddenly to do something such as answer the phone or stop children from doing something bad.

Comment: Do you mean that "Sure, I'll just drop everything and run off and get that. `Cause my movie is about to start." means "Sure, I **will not** just drop everything and run off and get that. `Cause my movie is about to start." in Russian?!

Comment: @Expelhares - You're right. The point is, that phrase is rather sarcastic and not too polite.

Comment: Yes, the intended meaning is the opposite of the literal meaning

Answer (score 2):

> What does “Сейчас всё брошу и побегу!” mean?

When person A sarcastically responds *«Сейчас всё брошу и побегу!»* to B's request, it means that

- A has negative emotions towards either B and/or B's request; A could be annoyed, feel underappreciated or disrespected.
- A implies that he/she has no intention to fulfill B's request, commonly on the ground of being busy or having better things to do at the moment.

It is rather unlikely, but still possible that there is no meaning-reversing sarcasm in that phrase. E.g. a boss can say *«Так, бросили всё и бегoм на медосмотр!»*
We know it's not the case as A mentioned that the movie is about to start, but if it were A would mean that

- A *is* going to stop doing anything else and hurry up to work on B's request right now.

> “Сейчас всё брошу и побегу!” is literally translated as "I will throw everything and run!" but I suppose that really it means something else

Translation (as usual) heavily depends on the context and translator's goals. As a translator you have to prioritize multiple things like

- making sure your audience understands the meaning to a good extent
- preserving original phrasing, idioms, and cultural references
- preserving multiple meanings when relevant
- matching the level of sarcasm and irony
- matching the register
- matching usage frequency of words and expressions
- matching the use of jargon words
- etc etc

The choice would be influenced by the expected reader audience familiarity with expressions, understanding the original culture and cross-cultural differences. E.g. if you need to simplify to the maximum, a translation can indeed be

> You're kidding, right?

Though this is a bit too far from the original: the reverse translation will turn *«Сейчас всё брошу и побегу!»* into *«Ты, конечно же, шутишь?»*.

One can try to preserve the original wording and pick closer idioms. However *и побегу* part implies too much and has a slim chance to survive the translation undamaged without becoming too vague and/or clumsy. I'd probably go with something along these options

> *Right, like I gonna [drop everything](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/drop+everything) and get your coffee!*
> *Oi! As if I gonna drop everything and fetch that!*
> *Oh, should I just drop everything and do as you say?!*

Answer (score 0):

- Listen, bun, would you fetch us some coffee?
- 1. That isn't even up for discussion!
  2. Not if you paid me!
  3. Like the hell I will!
  4. Fat chance!
  5. Nuts to you!
  6. Not on your life!
  7. Don't hold your breath!
  8. A fat lot will I do it!

Don't you see my film starting?!

Comment: Yeah, right. Like I'm gonna accept this answer.

Comment: You don't have to.

Answer (score -1):

Literal translation would be completely meaningless here. A better somewhat direct translation would be something like "I will stop whatever I am doing now and get going for it". But this is a sarcasm of course and it should not be translated directly. You should try to create a new sentence with as much close of a meaning as possible in your language. What is best to choose heavily depends on the context and on the translator itself and his awareness of traditions of the speakers.

And always remember that languages are not precise science. You can not completely depend on rules and dictionaries. They are just rough guidelines created to make it easier for you to start feeling the vibe of it. For Russian it is especially true.

Comment: you can completely rely on rules and dictionaries - and Russian is not exception for this, no language is special and every language is. If particular phrase is missing all that means is that the dictionary is incomplete. The other thing is that literal translation is impossible in many cases - but, again, this holds true about any language.

Answer (score -2):

"Сейчас всё брошу и побегу" означает:

- Мне что, делать нечего?
- Сам справишься.
- Я вам не официантка.
- Вот сам встал и принёс. Мне с сахаром.
- Ты не охренел, парниша?

Comment: you make it sound like this phrases are completely interchangeable but actually they are not - there are many cases when one can say "сейчас всё брошу и побегу"  but none of the phrases mentioned above would be applicable.

Answer (score -2):

Братуха, имеется ввиду что "ага заняться мне больше нечем"when russian say "сейчас всё брошу и побегу" he thinks f#ck you